# I am trying to set a timeout based on clock time

Tags: jenkins, groovy, timeout, jenkins-pipeline

I would like a jenkins pipeline to run a couple steps and then wait until 9 am ( or until the user clicks proceed/abort). I am open to other suggestions as well but was hoping to have an easy fix for this.

Here is the code snippet (there are stages following the wait) with timeout but I get a conversion error:

```
TimeoutStep.time expects int but received class java.lang.String
Could not instantiate {time=1033, unit=SECONDS} for TimeoutStep(time: int, unit?: TimeUnit[NANOSECONDS, MICROSECONDS, MILLISECONDS, SECONDS, MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS])

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages{
        stage('Within Approved Window') {
            agent { label 'Linux' }
            steps {
                isBuildWindow()
            }
        }        
        stage('Enable SCOM Maintenance Mode') {
            agent { label 'Windows' }
            when {
                expression { params.'Enable SCOM maintenance mode' == 'Yes' }
            }
            steps {
                build job: 'Powershell Components/startGroupMaintenanceMode', parameters: [string(name: 'ScomServer', value: '*********'), string(name: 'GroupDisplayName', value: '********'), string(name: 'DurationInMin', value: '90'), string(name: 'Reason', value: 'ApplicationInstallation'), string(name: 'Comment', value: 'Monthly Patching')]
            }
        }
        stage('Zero Control-M Initiators') {
            agent { label 'Linux' }
            when {
                expression { params.'Zero Control-M Initiators' == 'Yes' }
            }
            steps {
                sh '*****'
            }
        }
        stage('Wait til 9am') {
            agent { label 'Linux' }
            steps {
                timeout(time: env.sleep_seconds, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                    input message: 'Shall We Continue?'
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

void isBuildWindow() {
    script {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int dayOfWeek = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        int hourOfDay = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int sleep_seconds = 0
        if ( dayOfWeek != Calendar.SUNDAY || hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay > 10 ) {
            echo 'Outside Approved Build Window - Sunday between 8 and 11am'
            currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
            sh "exit 1"
        } else {
            echo 'Inside Approved Build Window - Sunday between 8 and 11am'
            Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);
            startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            sleep_seconds = ((startTime.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis()) / 1000);
            env.SLEEP_SECONDS = sleep_seconds
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The environment variables are probably always a string type. I suspect you can just cast them to an integer when you use them:

    timeout(time: env.sleep_seconds.toInteger(), unit: 'SECONDS') {
        input message: 'Shall We Continue?'
    }

Comment: Thanks... I could've sworn that I tried that. But I can't argue with success.   timeout(time: env.SLEEP_SECONDS.toInteger(), unit: 'SECONDS')